# Python read string as bytes without conversion

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I want to parse a command line string to bytes. From the command line is difficult to write some ASCII characters. I would like the user to enter a string of hex values and convert it to bytes. So if the user writes:

```
--byte_arg "\x41\x41"
```

My bytes variable should get two 41 values, not the decoded 'AA'.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do something similar enough to what I wanted with [binascii](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex):

```
import binascii

binascii.a2b_hex(args.)
```